# EditText is not working with the Navigation Component, when request focus called

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

Component used: Navigation
Version used: 2.2.0-alpha01
Devices/Android versions reproduced on: All compatible devices

When it happens?

It occurs when, there are two sequential fragments that call requestFocus() method on some EditText. The EditText is working properly only on the first fragment as the second EditText is not editable.

I investigated that it is somehow connected with the "setReorderingAllowed(true)" property which is set on the FragmentTransactions made with the NavigationComponent.

I have also created a [sample](https://github.com/KristiyanGergov/Navigation-Component-Bug-Sample) to simulate the problem. For simplicity I am creating the transaction between fragment on my own, instead of using the NavigationComponent